# How to pass a create a slice of a 2d array

Tags: go

I am having trouble to pass a slice of a 2d array of strings inside a func : this is my playground

[Golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yum_hTXJlh9)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    board := [2][3]string{
        {"O", "_", "O"},
        {"X", "O", "_"},
    }

    printBoard(board[:][:])
}

func printBoard(board [][]string){
    for _, line := range board {
        for _, cell := range line {
            fmt.Printf("%s", cell)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

It says `cannot use board[:][:] (type [][3]string) as type [][]string in argument to printBoard`

I did not manage to correct it printBoard(board[:][:]).

I tried by removing one/both semicolons inside the call, but did not work either. **I do not want to specify any length if possible**

Comment: Consider that `board[:][:]` is the same as `board[:]` or `board[:][:][:]`

Comment: Why didn't you declare the board variable as a slice of slices to begin with? Arrays, in golang, are rarely used. We tend to prefer slices 99% of the time, lest it be something insanely specific.

Comment: In fact it's just because I'm used to Java/Javascript, where slices does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In go, arrays have fixed sizes contrary to slices, so here you need to specify the size of your array as the argument, otherwise you will get this error:

`prog.go:13:12: cannot use board (type [2][3]string) as type [][]string in argument to printBoard`

Here it is [fixed](https://play.golang.org/p/DACllIIGIMA):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    board := [2][3]string{
        {"O", "_", "O"},
        {"X", "O", "_"},
    }

    printBoard(board)
}

func printBoard(board [2][3]string){
    for _, line := range board {
        for _, cell := range line {
            fmt.Printf("%s", cell)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Outputs

> ```
> O_O
> XO_
> ```

I'm not sure why you decided to use arrays but in go, whenever possible you should prefer using slices instead of arrays, as they're more flexible, cleaner and less bug-prone.

Here is the implementation with slices instead:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    board := [][]string{
        {"O", "_", "O"},
        {"X", "O", "_"},
    }

    printBoard(board)
}

func printBoard(board [][]string){
    for _, line := range board {
        for _, cell := range line {
            fmt.Printf("%s", cell)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to change your logic, and you don't need to specify sizes anywhere anymore.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to avoid giving at least one size in the call ?

Comment: By using slices instead.

Comment: Like this: https://play.golang.org/p/buplWcRfoAF It's simpler and you don't need to specify any size anywhere.

Comment: Oh yes, I managed to omit the first dimension : [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dqQFYEdT5uz)

Comment: You should probably just use slices instead: https://gobyexample.com/slices Unless you have a good reason to want to use arrays.

Comment: slices consumes more memory and cpu than arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, coming from other languages, I forgot that slices are far better.